# Comparing current time to specific time range

Tags: python

`please help`

```
import datetime

TimeCheck = datetime.datetime.now()
RunStart = datetime.time(23, 0, 0)
RunEnd = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)

if TimeCheck < RunStart and TimeCheck > RunEnd
         print("Run Success")

    elif TimeCheck = RunStart and TimeCheck = RunEnd:
        print("Run Sucess")

        else 
        print(Run Failed)
```

this is the output

hellowolrd.py", line 7
    if
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS I'm NewBS

Comment: `elif` needs to be in the same indentation as `if`

Comment: You also need a colon at the end of the `if` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few issues with your Syntax, see comments on what you missed;

```
import datetime

TimeCheck = datetime.datetime.now()
RunStart = datetime.time(23, 0, 0)
RunEnd = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)

if TimeCheck < RunStart and TimeCheck > RunEnd: # ':' was missing
         print("Run Success")

elif TimeCheck == RunStart and TimeCheck == RunEnd: # Indentation was incorrect, '=' should have been '=='
         print("Run Sucess")

else: #Indentation was incorrect, ':' was missing
        print("Run Failed") # "" was missing
```

Then to top it off, your code still will not work until you solve the below error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

This would be a great opportunity to read up on Python syntax, which I would recommend you do before tackling the next error.

[Python Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics)

Comment: It's rare to see objective, yet simple answers lately here.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple syntax errors... here it is cleaned up.

```py
import datetime

TimeCheck = datetime.datetime.now()
RunStart = datetime.time(23, 0, 0)
RunEnd = datetime.time(1, 0, 0)

if TimeCheck < RunStart and TimeCheck > RunEnd:
    print("Run Success")

elif TimeCheck == RunStart and TimeCheck == RunEnd:
    print("Run Success")

else:
    print("Run Failed")
```

Comment: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even want to think about the semantics of their code, I was just cleaning up the syntax.